# Django asks for session in every request (even image/css/etc). How to handle this?

Tags: django, session

I installed the devserver package, and i can see in sql log that for a requests, django asks for session multiple times, for every static media. How to stop this ?

Comment: Devserver obviously isn't meant to for production... So in what scenario is this an issue?

Comment: this is intentional since you might want to limit access to your static resources or apply access control mechanism on them based on the session.

Comment: well, using the devserver. i didn't try with apache, mod_python, etc

Comment: mod_python is dead... try mod_wsgi instead.

Comment: I use nginx to serve static files, and to reverse proxy to apache+mod_wsgi+django in production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stop serving your media from django...
Use nginx or another webserver to handle media requests.